# Pass metadata when replayed in jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to restart a build using the replay option provided from pipepline plugin.

When i click on replay the jenkinsfile script is displayed, that's completely fine.

Is there a way to pass some metadata from the current build to the new build when replayed?

Comment: What do you mean with that? Parameters? Are you missing them, when triggering via _Replay_? I'd say that function isn't made for day-to-day work, more for pipeline development.

Comment: I want to pass some environment variable/parameters from the current build to the new build when triggered using replay. Is it possible?
This is required in case of build failure that needs to be restarted again.